# vectorize with np.dot of matrix and an array

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

I won't to make my program faster, but I don't find a solution to vectorize this function

```
def error_probability(y, sample_x, beta, func):
    """
    :param y: Float
    :param sample_x: Numpy Array with dim (n,2)
    :param beta:  Numpy Array with dim (2,)
    :param func: Just a function
    :return: Median of all values of the function func
    """
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(sample_x)):
        sum = sum + func(y - np.dot(beta, sample_x[i, :]))
    return sum / len(sample_x)
```

I already tried it with this

```
def error_probability(y, sample_x, beta, func):
    residuals = y - sample_x.dot(beta)
    errors = func(residuals)
    return np.sum(errors) / sample_x.shape[0]
```

But this does not work.

Comment: if possible please create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At very least you should provide definition of `func`, because it needs to be vectorized as well